# python-fu gimp get items list

Tags: gimp, gimpfu

How can I get the list of items in an image using python-fu? I've tried searching for a similar function in Python Procedure Browser and google but I couldn't find any. (My end goal is to select a text item on a layer and convert it to a path)

Edit - Using GIMP version 2.8.2 on macOS Mojave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't list "items" in general. You list layers, channels, or paths, either using the PDB:

```
for lid in pdb.gimp_image_get_layers(image)
for cid in pdb.gimp_image_get_channels(image)
for vid in pdb.gimp_image_get_vectors(image)
```

or the attributes of the image object:

```
for l in image.layers
for c in image.channels
for v in image.vectors
```

The PDB calls return integer item IDs (use `gimp._id2drawable(id)`/`gimp._id2vectors(id)` to get the objects), while the image attributes are lists of `gimp.Layer`/`gimp.Channel`/`gimp.Vector` objects (and are therefore much simpler to work with).

To tell if a layer is a text layer, you have to use a PDB call: `pdb.gimp_item_is_text_layer(layer)`

You can iterate the text layers thus

```
for textlayer in [l for l in image.layers if pdb.gimp_item_is_text_layer(l)]`
```

To get the path from a text layer:

```
path=pdb.gimp_vectors_new_from_text_layer(image,layer)
```

Many sample Python scripts [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) and some more specialized in paths [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/).